# Regular expression for matching date

Tags: c#, regex, datetime, datetime-format

I have no knowledge of regular expressions except using **Regex** library in C# , that too with pattern matching expressions searched from net.

I would like to have regex to match date in below two mentioned formats , no need for Year part.

1. `8 October` or `8 Oct`
2. `September 19` or `Sep 19`

Please help me out , searching Google hasn't helped me .

Comment: Why was this question voted to close as `too localized`? It seems like a perfectly valid question to me. The only valid reason why this question might be voted to close is `not a real question` for the lack of research from the OP and not showing what he has tried so far. But I wouldn't vote for close as not a real question because the OP simply went into the wrong direction for searching for a regular expression to solve this issue.

Comment: Agreed, I'll vote to leave open but op should put what he tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  string Date = "December 8"

  MatchCollection MC = Regex.Matches(Date, @"(?i)([\d]{1,2}(\s)?(January|Jan|February|feb|March|mar|April|Apr|May|June|July|August|Aug|September|Sep|October|Oct|November|Nov|December|Dec))|(January|Jan|February|feb|March|mar|April|Apr|May|June|July|August|Aug|September|Sep|October|Oct|November|Nov|December|Dec)(\s)?[\d]{1,2}");
```

Answer (score 6):

Why struggle with regular expressions when the framework already provides you with the [`TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) method which is designed to do exactly that:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var str = "8 October";
        DateTime date;
        var formats = new[] { "d MMMM", "d MMM" };
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The date was not in one of the 2 supported formats 'd MMMM' orr 'd MMM'");
        }
    }
}
```

You could even make it culture aware. For example let's suppose that you have french speaking users of your site that would probably write `8 Octobre` instead of `8 October`.

In this case you could specify the current culture or force a specific culture:

```
var str = "8 Octobre";
DateTime date;
var formats = new[] { "d MMMM", "d MMM" };
var ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // use the date instance here
}
```

Further reading: [custom datetime formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: Only an assumption, but I think the OP needs to find the dates at first in a larger string and to find such possible dates, regex is fine. Of course the "possible" date needs then to be checked using your method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
(?<month>[a-zA-Z]+)\s+(?<day>\d+)|(?<day>\d+)\s+(?<month>[a-zA-Z]+)
```

and get groups named: `day` and `month`

Answer (score 1):

To find a date in a larger string you could do something like this:

```
\b(?:\d{1,2}\s(?:Jan|Feb|Sep|Oct)(?:[a-z]+\b)?|(?:Jan|Feb|Sep|Oct)(?:[a-z]+\b)?\s\d{1,2})\b
```

Together with the option `IgnoreCase`.

And **then test the resulting strings with the methods [Darin Dimitrov provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12796652/626273)**

Of course you need to complete the list of abbreviations. I added only some for test.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?32da2)

Answer (score 1):

If you must to use regex try this

```
((?<Day>\d\d?) (?<Month>[A-Z][a-z]+))|((?<Month>[A-Z][a-z]+) (?<Day>\d\d?))
```